# remove top margin for <body> in smaller screen sizes - Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, margin, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm not sure whether I'm right or not. I have built a webpage using Bootstrap 4. After a lot of tweaks, all the page elements are rendering as expected. But, in smaller screens it appears as if the `<body>` has `top-margin` which is pushing some of my elements with `position: absolute`. I tried going through the CSS file but found no such code. It's the last bit left in my code.

**My Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/3kjdo9rr/10/

Please have a look at the screenshots for better understanding. I have placed my mouse pointer on the `<body>` in my Google Chrome Developer Tools.

**Large Screens**

[image]

**Small Screen (iPhone 6S Portrait)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The demo isnt' quite what you show but there is a gap.
It is the  element and the class .pad which has     margin: 4rem 1.5rem 1rem 1.5rem; if you change it to margin: 3rem 1.5rem 1rem 1.5rem; the gap closes up.

Comment: That works. Thanks. But that doesn't serve my purpose. I'm sorry I didn't mention that in the question. I want the margin for .pad but push the pseudo elements .clip::after and .clip::before as shown in Screenshot 1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that this gap is caused by top margin on .pad class. So change it to something like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.pad {
  margin: 0 1.5rem 1rem 1.5rem;

}
```

Comment: Please refer to my comment to Glenn Packer's answer. I'm trying to retain the exact design.